# Create clickable link in table to show more details when clicked

Tags: laravel, routes

```html
<tbody style="text-align: center!important;">
    @foreach ($freeToday as $key => $item)
        <tr style="height: 21px;">
            <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                <span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->gameTime)->format('H:i') }}</span>
            </td>
            <td><span>{{ $item->league }}</span></td>
            <td style="background-color: #ffffff;"><span>{{ $item->teamOne }}
                    <span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>VS</strong></span>
                    {{ $item->teamTwo }}</span></td>
            <td><span><strong>{{ $item->FTRecommendation }}</strong></span></td>
             <td><a href="{{ url('/gamedetails') }}/{{ $value->id }}" data-target="/gamedetail" data-toggle="modal"><span style="color: green;"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span> VIEW</span></a>

             </td>
            <td>
                @if ($item->FreePickStatus == '1')
                    <span class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></span>
                @elseif($item->FreePickStatus=="2")
                    <span class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger" style="color:red;"></span>
                @elseif($item->FreePickStatus=='3')
                    <span style="color:red">pstp</span>
                @else
                    ?
                @endif
            </td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I have the above table in my home blade which displays matches already saved to the database, now what I am trying to achieve is when a visitor clicks on the view button, it will open a new window to show all the match details for that particular match.
I have this in my gamedetails.blade.php

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
                $g11 = substr($game->teamOneForm, 0, 1);          $g12 = substr($game->teamOneForm, 1, 1);
                $g13 = substr($game->teamOneForm, 2, 1);          $g14 = substr($game->teamOneForm, 3, 1);
                $g15 = substr($game->teamOneForm, 4, 1);

                $g21 = substr($game->teamTwoForm, 0, 1);          $g22 = substr($game->teamTwoForm, 1, 1);
                $g23 = substr($game->teamTwoForm, 2, 1);          $g24 = substr($game->teamTwoForm, 3, 1);
                $g25 = substr($game->teamTwoForm, 4, 1);
            ?>
            <style>
                .class1{color: white; background: green; padding: 3px 8px; border-radius: 100px; font-weight: bold;}
                .class2{color: green; background: yellow; padding: 4px 10px; border-radius: 100px; font-weight: bold;}
                .class3{color: white; background: red; padding: 3px 10px; border-radius: 100px; font-weight: bold;}
                .cont{margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;}
            </style>

                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td><h3 class="cont">{{$game->teamOne}}</h3></td>
                        <td rowspan="3" style="background: darkgreen; color: red; text-align: center" valign="bottom">VS</td>
                        <td><h3 class="cont">{{$game->teamTwo}}</h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @if($g11=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g11}}</span>    @elseif ($g11=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g11}}</span>
                            @else    <span class="class3">{{$g11}}</span>   @endif

                            @if($g12=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g12}}</span> @elseif ($g12=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g12}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g12}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g13=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g13}}</span> @elseif ($g13=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g13}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g13}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g14=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g14}}</span> @elseif ($g14=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g14}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g14}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g15=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g15}}</span> @elseif ($g15=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g15}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g15}}</span>    @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if($g21=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g21}}</span>    @elseif ($g21=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g21}}</span>
                            @else    <span class="class3">{{$g21}}</span>   @endif

                            @if($g22=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g22}}</span> @elseif ($g22=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g22}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g22}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g23=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g23}}</span> @elseif ($g23=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g23}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g23}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g24=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g24}}</span> @elseif ($g24=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g24}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g24}}</span>    @endif

                            @if($g25=='W') <span class="class1">{{$g25}}</span> @elseif ($g25=='D') <span class="class2">{{$g25}}</span>
                            @else     <span class="class3">{{$g25}}</span>    @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 120%;"><strong>ODDS: </strong>{{$game->teamOneOdds}}</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 120%;"><strong>ODDS: </strong>{{$game->teamTwoOdds}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @if($game->teamOneWon=='')
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="background: darkgreen; color: red; text-align: center"><center>RESULT NOT YET ADDED</center></td>
                        </tr>
                        @else
                        <tr>
                            <td style="background: darkgreen; color: red;"><b>Score: </b> {{$game->teamOneScore}}</td>
                            <td style="background: darkgreen; color: red;"><center></center></td>
                            <td style="background: darkgreen; color: red;"><b>Score: </b> {{$game->teamTwoScore}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                    @if($game->cornerStatus=='1')
                        <tr>
                            <th>Corner Result</th>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{{$game->cornerResult}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                </table>
                
        </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I click, it shows me a page not found.  Please, how do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where is the `$value` variable coming from in the first set of code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u have registered that route.

First off all i would recommend to use something like [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('/gamedetails/{game}', [GameController::class, 'show'])->name('game.show');
```

by doing this way u can create a link in your blade somehting like this:

```
{{route('game.show', $item)}}
```

item in this case would be the item u wanna visit which would be the object **Game** or what your object is named.

Than for the controller u would have the show function that would look something like this:

```
 public function show(Game $game)
{
    return view('game.show', [
        'game'     => $game,
    ]);
}
```

Of course u would have to put in the Model to the model u have. [More info here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers)